# Container View bounds issue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, containers

I'm writing a function which can get the height and width of the container view:

```
// container view's UIViewController
class SelectionView: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func getBounds -> (CGFloat,CGFloat){
        let x = self.view.bounds.width / 5
        let y = self.view.bounds.height / 15
        return x,y
    }

}
```

I write a button to call this getBounds() and it works well, but when I put it in the viewDidLoad() function

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getBounds()
}
```

getBounds() returns me different height and width and it is clearly not the bounds of this container view.

I'm pretty sure I've linked this class to the container view!

Comment: Did you try the method in viewDidAppear() method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

View layout is not setup in `viewDidLoad`. Therefore any resizing is not done yet and your size is wrong(probably the same as declared in Storyboard/Xib).

Move `getBounds` in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewWillAppear` and it will work correctly. Please mind that those method won't be called one time only ;)

Answer (score 1):

The view hasn't been laid out in viewDidLoad, you will likely need to catch it in a later method or in viewDidLayoutSubviews.